# Create a trigger in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, database

I am trying to create a trigger for a cinema database.
I need it to update once a rating is added for a movie showing the text "rating added". The table name is

movie_ratings

the primary key is = movie_rating

I am not really sure how to do it, I have looked online but still are not too sure. I was wondering if anyone could help.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want the "rating added" text to go?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the syntax to create a trigger which will fire when a row is inserted.

```
create trigger movie_rating_added on movie_ratings for insert
as 
   -- trigger code goes here

go
```

Inside the trigger, you have access to a virtual table called `inserted`, which has the same schema as `movie_ratings`, but which contains only the rows which were inserted.

I'm not clear on exactly what you want the trigger to do, but for example you could do something like this:

```
create trigger movie_rating_added on movie_ratings for insert
as
    update m set last_action = "rating added"
    from movies m
    join inserted i on i.movie_id=m.id
go
```

Which is supposing the existence of some fields and tables that you might not have, but hopefully it gives you a useful example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, thats useful. Im pretty new to this so not 100% sure on what you mean as -- trigger code goes here, Im not sure what to insert there.

Again Thanks for you time